PDA for $\{a^i b^j c^k : i \neq j \}$
I am trying to write a PDA for $L := \{ a^i b^j c^k : i, j \in \Bbb{N} \land i \neq j \}$, but I am getting stuck since I am new with Automaton Theory. My idea was to make PDAs for both $\{ a^i b^j c^k : i < j \}$ and $\{ a^i b^j c^k : i > j \}$ and join them which is easier, but I obtain so many states and I intuit that it must be a way simpler that I am not seeing to do this, so any possible help or solution would be appreciated.
EDIT


I am assuming you are following a standard PDA construction procedure. That is you push some symbol (say $A$) for every $a$ you read and pop that symbol for every $b$. Eventually you will end up in one of the following cases:
case $i < j$:
Since there are more $b$s than $a$s, there will be deficit of $A$s in the stack. Thus, on reading a $b$ you will observe the empty stack symbol. Just consume all the $b$s you read and then all the $c$s and go to the final state to accept the string.
case $i > j$:
You will read a $c$ while stack top will have an $A$ (and not the empty stack symbol). You just consume all the $c$s, pop the remaining $A$s (if needed), and go to the final state to accept the string.
case $i = j$:
You will read a $c$ while stack top will have the empty stack symbol.
You just consume all the $c$s, but this time you go to some other [terminal] state to reject the string.

Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me if what I added is fine?

There are wonderful tools available online where you can construct your PDA, try a bunch of inputs, and try to validate and convince yourself if the PDA is correct or not. Of course, you can dry run with your own hand, but playing with the tools is easy and fun.

Thanks! I will try
